# Sending transaction error: -26: non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)

Tags: transactions, signature, sending

I'm not sure what the problem is here, everything seems correct, but I'm new to this and I'm obviously missing something. Can someone pinpoint the issue causing the error?

Hex:   `0100000000010126bd2466fc4f56e67aaa4a16944a705e1e23d3a5fcdec61ff9207f2e646456d00100000000ffffffff02e803000000000000160014bc6bbe01c11150f9e857b71003848d29ed7ea37d5e0e00000000000016001440c2b89bd81eb70c2ad2cd2ae1a798740bd7b0b902473044022064eec9b7b5428ceac3729aceb2acc51bb5fe8d982f05163659034d3d811766130220232ec91b3d5838d2ea6a3c6d8ebbc9e96d020c3541de49ec5dff0ffb0c46b263012103d35369bf96713564518c4d0139dacfdfcc2782afdde2a545a5e86865a85b6d5500000000`

Raw transaction:

```
{
    "block_height": -1,
    "block_index": -1,
    "hash": "63d38c7131a802225fa7c73488666e120e2b8b4e473759b0ef963117abd8e485",
    "addresses": [
        "bc1qtf5qu5ymuyfgehy7lmkqf25arx4h8q3ynpqkwu",
        "bc1qh34muqwpz9g0n6zhkugq8pyd98khagmanhqglx",
        "bc1qgrpt3x7cr6msc2kje54wrfucws9a0v9e7mkzyh"
    ],
    "total": 4678,
    "fees": 939,
    "size": 222,
    "vsize": 141,
    "preference": "low",
    "relayed_by": "37.19.221.228",
    "received": "2023-11-01T00:52:25.356769851Z",
    "ver": 1,
    "double_spend": false,
    "vin_sz": 1,
    "vout_sz": 2,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "prev_hash": "d05664642e7f20f91fc6defca5d3231e5e704a94164aaa7ae6564ffc6624bd26",
            "output_index": 1,
            "output_value": 5617,
            "sequence": 4294967295,
            "addresses": [
                "bc1qtf5qu5ymuyfgehy7lmkqf25arx4h8q3ynpqkwu"
            ],
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash",
            "age": 805996,
            "witness": [
                "3044022064eec9b7b5428ceac3729aceb2acc51bb5fe8d982f05163659034d3d811766130220232ec91b3d5838d2ea6a3c6d8ebbc9e96d020c3541de49ec5dff0ffb0c46b26301",
                "03d35369bf96713564518c4d0139dacfdfcc2782afdde2a545a5e86865a85b6d55"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "value": 1000,
            "script": "0014bc6bbe01c11150f9e857b71003848d29ed7ea37d",
            "addresses": [
                "bc1qh34muqwpz9g0n6zhkugq8pyd98khagmanhqglx"
            ],
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash"
        },
        {
            "value": 3678,
            "script": "001440c2b89bd81eb70c2ad2cd2ae1a798740bd7b0b9",
            "addresses": [
                "bc1qgrpt3x7cr6msc2kje54wrfucws9a0v9e7mkzyh"
            ],
            "script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash"
        }
    ]
}
```